# Не видит переменные в Адаптере

Tags: recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, recycleview, recyclerviewadapter

Есть адаптер для RecyclerViev.

```
package com.example.dimab.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public AdapterRecycler(List<ListItem> listItems, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);

        holder.textViewHead.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.textViewDesc.setText(listItem.getDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewHead;
        public TextView textViewDesc;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewHead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHead);
            textViewDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

В методе `onBindViewHolder` не видит переменные `textViewHead` и `textViewDesc`

Comment: а в конструкторе они присваиваются? Можете продебажить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в этом

```
public class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

не правильно пронаследовался

```
public class AdapterRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecycler.ViewHolder>
```

Правильно вот так

Comment: Правильно и так, как было, и так, как вы переделали. Только в первом случае в `onBindViewHolder` при обращении к `holder` требуется явное преобразование `(AdapterRecycler.ViewHolder) holder`. Тогда будете иметь доступ к полям вашего `holder`